# Robotframework: Suite variable not found in 2nd test case

Tags: variables, robotframework, suite

Hi does anybody know why I cannot reference suite variable defined in TC1 and then referencing it TC2 within one suite I am getting error : Variable not found
Running both tests is ok, but runnig tc1 and then tc2 will produce this error
Python 2.7.13
Ride: 1.7.3.1
Thanx a lot
[TC1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoHE8.jpg)
[TC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irVUj.jpg)

Comment: Add a sample code, without it the question is too vague. How are you setting the variable in TC1, with which keyword? The default variable scope is the current case, only.

Comment: The problem is definitely somewhere in your code. This is a feature or robot that has thoroughly been tested. There is no way we can solve this problem unless you can show us a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @TodorMinakov,  thanx for your comment , I have updated my question with code snippets from TC1 and TC2

Comment: @BryanOakley , I ve added example pics from both cases, I d like to know that for how long is the suite variable stored? is it remembered until TC is run again , or this scenario works only if TC1 and TC2 are runned in sequence. thanx

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. As for how long a suite variable is stored, it's stored for the life of the suite.

Answer (score 1):

Try next simple code and say if it works, main point here is where you define suite variable by `Set Suite Variable`, it should be in the first test case or in the one of the setups(Test/Suite Setup):

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Collections

*** Test Cases ***
TestCase1
    Log to Console    ${EMPTY}
    Set Suite Variable    ${suite_variable}    case1
    Log To Console    I'm in case 1: ${suite_variable}

TestCase2
    Log to Console    ${EMPTY}
    ${variables}    Get Variables
    Dictionary Should Contain Key    ${variables}    \${suite_variable}
    Log To Console    I'm in case 2: ${suite_variable}
```

Comment: I tried, running TestCase1 and right after TestCase2 works correctly, but then I run let say TC3 and than did again TestCase2 and it failled with:                                                                                           
| FAIL |
Dictionary does not contain key '${suite_variable}'.
For how long is the suite variable stored or persisted?

Comment: Until Suite is finished. If you run full suite it should work.
If you run each test case separately by `pybot` command it will not work. I suggest create simple script without any actions to see if it works or not and publish it here.